# Dealing with flat file quote escapes when running BCP IN on files created by Pandas to_csv

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, export-to-csv, bcp

I am trying to get a process going in python to write data into a .csv which can then be BCP'd into a MSSQL database.

The basic to_csv command I am using is:

```
df.to_csv(csv_path, sep = "«", header = False, index = False, line_terminator="[~~]")
```

The one issue I have been seeing is how the program handles double quotes within text. If a set of double quotes is found, it quote-escapes it.

So a row which looks like:

```
    1, 7, Executed Job: "abcdf" Complete
```

Gets turned into this when loaded into the data:

```
    1, 7, "Executed Job: ""abcdf"" Complete"
```

The current BCP command I'm using is:

```
bcp database.dbo.table in "csv_path" -S server 
-U uname -P pword -T -C RAW -r "[~~]" 
-t"«" -e error_test.txt -f "xml_path"
```

When I load this data into the database, it sometimes produces an error if the extra quotes bring the string above the character limit. Also it's incorrect data in general, so I don't want to load it in this way.

I'm aware of setting a different escape and setting quoting to csv.QUOTE_NONE, but that seems to create other issues with how the BCP reads the file. Namely if I feed it a character like "»" in the escapechar argument, that gets read into the database with the » included because it doesn't realize it as an escape character.

I am loading it into a staging table first, so it may be possible for me to just update the "T" portion of the ELT to handle it, but that seems like it could be a mess. Is there any way to configure my to_csv + BCP settings to circumvent this problem?

P.S. The reason for the silly characters as delimiters/terminators is that some of the data uses nearly every character, to the point where even | is not a safe delimiter.

Edit: I tried using doublequote = False with to_csv but still ran into errors down the line. I specifically got a "needs to escape but no escape character set" error.

Comment: another option besides what you answered for yourself... Skip delimiters altogether... used a fixed width file.

Comment: Also, your title states "csv" but your file is not a csv.

Comment: oh, nevermind about fixed-width, your data is coming out of pandas. missed that.

Comment: I am using to_csv to write even if it is not technically a csv. Is there a way to write a fixed width file from a pandas dataframe?

Comment: furthermore, is there a way to batch write a fixed width file? If so I am fine using that.

Comment: sorry. cant help with pandas. good luck!

Comment: what errors did you get further down the line with using doublequote=false?

Comment: needs to escape but no escape character set

Comment: I see. this is an error from the Pandas tool "to_csv", correct?

Comment: in this instance yes

Comment: if your search goes on too long, you may want to just load into SQL and manipulate there. Just load the entire line of data into a single column in SQL. Use a string split function to tear out individual field values. Then replace "" with " when found. It's not quite the simple, but that is the jist. You'll need to avoid replacing any fields that are quoted and are empty (if that happens)... ,"",

Comment: I believe it would be better to create a flat file if possible. Having to manually replace escapes in SQL may be comparatively time consuming when dealing with 100M+ records overall.